# multiple domain redirection with htaccess rewrite rules

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am looking for a way to redirect all my old domains to a new domain ,

It seems they are redirected in basic level , but when it comes the sub categories or perm links , no redirection works at all.

```
    Options +FollowSymLinks 
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (www\.)?mydomain1\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (www\.)?mydomain2\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (www\.)?mydomain3\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (www\.)?mydomain4\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (www\.)?mydomain5\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (www\.)?mydomain6\.com$ [NC]

    RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.mydomain7.com/$1 [QSA,L,R=301]
```

basic level redirection is fine : mydomain1.com/graph.php   = > mydomain7.com

but even in this level it can't redirect to same page

and more importantly the perm-links :

mydomain1.com/users/13/James    => no redirection

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cleanest solution would be to redirect any domain that is not www.mydomain7.com

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mydomain7\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.mydomain7.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 2):

All the RewriteCond are ANDed together by default and hence your rules won't work because value of `%{HTTP_HOST}` cannot be all those domains at the same time.

Either use negation as suggested by Gerben or rewrite your code like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(mydomain1|mydomain2|mydomain3|mydomain4|mydomain5|mydomain6)\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.mydomain7.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```